# unable to upload file to box using JWT - curl: (26) failed creating formpost data

Tags: java, linux, curl, box

I am executing below command using cURL in java. This gives me error - right after a white space after `Bearer`.

`2019-07-25 08:04:09,297  INFO [com.pc.boxapi.BoxApi:198] - curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk"'`

```java
curlCommand = "curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content  -H \"Authorization:Bearer Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk\" -X POST  -F attributes='{\"name\":\"text.txt\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"69430965158\"}}' -F file=@file.txt\"";

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curlCommand);
LOG.info("process {} ", process.getOutputStream().toString());
```

if I use a forward slash between `Bearer` and `Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk`
I get another error -

```
INFO [com.pc.boxapi.BoxApi:198] - curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
```

Server is Linux

Comment: Your command isn't correctly splitted (`-H \"Authorization:Bearer` and `Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk\"` are parsed as two separate words). It might be possible to fix that using `Process.runtime(String[] cmdarray)` instead, in which you have control over the various tokens of the command. I would also recommend using the `ProcessBuilder` class instead of `Runtime`, but I'd even more recommend using Java APIs rather than a call to the curl binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `man` page of `curl` says that error code 26 stands for `Read error. Various reading problems.`.

If you just print the command you're trying to execute, you get this :

```sh
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content  -H "Authorization:Bearer Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk" -X POST  -F attributes='{"name":"text.txt","parent":{"id":"69430965158"}}' -F file=@file.txt"
```

A read problem is probably related to `-F file=@file.txt"`. Notice the extra `"` at the end of the filename. I'm pretty sure your problem is here. Remove it and make sure `file.txt` exists.

By the way, if you need to make HTTP requests in Java, you should use a library like [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).

Avoid executing a system command at all costs, it's a security issue waiting to append!

Comment: I agree. if I execute the command in terminal it works well. but when I try to execute it in java it give me error `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk"' ` . it is breaking after `Authorization:Bearer ` since there is a white space. how to escape a white space here?.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message `Couldn't resolve host 'Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk"'`, curl parsed `Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk` as an hostname, which means it received `Authorization:Bearer` and `Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk` as two separate parameters when you obviously wanted it as a single one.

I suggest using the `Process.runtime(String[] cmdarray)` method instead of `Process.runtime(String cmd)`, in which you will be the one splitting the command into multiple tokens :

```
String[] curlCommand = { "curl", "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content",  
    "-H", "Authorization:Bearer Ddu9DLiWt2YRWxtsoAxjL0BMMbt9FvOk", "-X", "POST", 
    "-F", "attributes={\"name\":\"text.txt\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"69430965158\"}}",
    "-F", "file=@file.txt"
};
Process.runtime(curlCommand);
```

Also note that the `@file.txt` reference is a relative one : it relies on the presence of a `file.txt` file in the current working directory (unless changed, the one you executed your java code from).